# LibGDX - Your android sdk path doesn't contain an sdk

Tags: android, sdk, libgdx

I have android studio installed on my computer and I already developed a few apps, so I think I should have the SDK installed properly, and now I'm trying to learn game programming apps. I use LibGDX, when I use the LibGDX project generator to generate project, I'm getting an error

Your android sdk path doesn't contain an sdk, including all platforms and build tools!

What's interesting is it used to work. I haven't touch it in a while and now trying to go back to it and it stop working. Also, I started with eclipse, and then moved to android studio, not sure if that has anything to do with it. The weird thing is my eclipse which I haven't work with in a while also stopped working.

[image: error]

the following is a screen shot of the sdk folder
[image]

Comment: We can't see the paths in both screenshots, if they're the same and point to the SDK's root (example: C:\android\sdk) then maybe you should try opening the SDK Manager and check if you have the platforms and build-tools installed like stated in the error message.

Comment: I didn't know what the error meant until you mentioned. That was indeed the case, some tools was not installed and the build needs update. How do I mark your answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: This is just a comment, you can't accept it as an answer. I'll post my comment as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't see the paths in both screenshots, if they're the same and point to the SDK's root (example: C:\android\sdk) then maybe you should try opening the SDK Manager and check if you have the platforms and build-tools installed like stated in the error message.